# Split string when reading a file and ignore one string LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a file like

```
56.32 211.398      1 81.0966
56.55 21.6862      1 51.2413
56.48 21.4071      2 298.1962
52.69 211.017      2 262.2705
53.88 211.759      3 258.1490
56.08 21.3705      3 262.2397
```

I want to save it to a List, removing the integer on the third position
so I would get

```
56.32, 211.398, 81.0966
56.55, 21.6862, 51.2413
56.48, 21.4071, 298.1962
52.69, 211.017, 262.2705
53.88, 211.759, 258.1490
56.08, 21.3705, 262.2397
```

I was trying:

```
List<double[]> fileData = new List<double[]>();
fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
          .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' },
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(y => double.Parse(y))
          .ToArray())
          .ToList();
```

But I am getting the following, how to ignore the third number?

```
56.32, 211.398,1, 81.0966
56.55, 21.6862,1, 51.2413
56.48, 21.4071,2, 298.1962
52.69, 211.017,2, 262.2705
53.88, 211.759,3, 258.1490
56.08, 21.3705,3, 262.2397
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) overload that uses a lambda that takes the index and filter by that index:

```
List<double[]> fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
          .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Where((s, index) => index != 2) // filters out the third column
             .Select(y => double.Parse(y))
             .ToArray())
          .ToList();
```

Comment: In `Select(y => double.Parse(y))` the `y` is `string[]`. How do you pass it to `double.Parse`?

Comment: @JohnyL I admit that it's not _so_ readable and maybe I should change indentation, but please check the parantheses: the _inner_ where and select calls are targeting the result of `Split` _inside_ the first outer select.

Comment: Ah! Spot it! 

Comment: Posted another solution of mine 

Answer (score 0):

I expect adding a where clause before your final select should do the trick:

```
List<double[]> fileData = new List<double[]>();
fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
          .Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '\t', ' ' },
                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Where(s=>s.Contains(".")
          .Select(y => double.Parse(y))
          .ToArray())
          .ToList();
```

Comment: This will take all except third!

Answer (score 0):

Regex to the rescue:

```
var doubles = Regex.Split(text, @"\s{2,}\d+\s|\r\n|\s").Select(s => double.Parse(s));
```